# Center parent div issue

Tags: html, css

My problem is with the CSS: I want to center the `#product-section`, while the `.product-img` should all be aligned as they are currently. To clarify: I want all products to be centered, but lined up as they currently are.

The parent div (which I want to be centered):

```
#product-section {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    padding-left: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: red;
}
```

The products (which should be lined up as in the picture):

```
.product-img {
    width: 220px;
    height: 220px;
    border: 2px solid #F3F3F3;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 30px 15px 0 0;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.product-img img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    height: 150px;
    width: 80%;
}

.product-img h3 {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin: 20px 0 0 0;
    background-color: #F3F3F3;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    color: #6C6C6C;
}
```

The Header Text

```
.category {
    font-size: 64px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 50px auto 0 auto;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="product-section">
<h2 class="category">Mejeri</h2>

<div id="Mjölk" class="product-img product added"><h4><span>6</span> st</h4><img src="assets/icons/milk.png"><h3>Mjölk</h3></div>

</div>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please add a HTML markup.

Comment: Have you tried adding margin: 0 auto; in your #product-section css?
Just guessing, don't really know what the HTML is behind this all.

Comment: Use `text-align:center` on the parent of **#product-section** since you have inline-block on it that should work

Comment: Updated with HTML @Zephire

Comment: Updated with HTML @panther

Comment: `1st`, `2st`, `3st` :|

Comment: @user3284463 If I'm not mistaken, those are Danish cardinal numbers (as in "n pieces") - not misspelled English ordinal numbers :o)